turf intersect doesn't capture all intersections
I'm trying to calculate the intersection of these polygons, however it isn't capturing all intersections.
I'm using this site to visualise it: https://turf-sandbox.netlify.app/
const coordinates = [
    [
    [ 4.307274211471829, 52.08387390249157 ],
  [ 4.30846, 52.07541 ],
  [ 4.3101, 52.0759 ],
  [ 4.30912, 52.07672 ],
  [ 4.30819, 52.07789 ],
  [ 4.30884, 52.07841 ],
  [ 4.30985, 52.07858 ],
  [ 4.3103, 52.07888 ],
  [ 4.3104, 52.07959 ],
  [ 4.31024, 52.07997 ],
  [ 4.30881, 52.08128 ],
  [ 4.30913, 52.08163 ],
  [ 4.30922, 52.08209 ],
  [ 4.3077, 52.08356 ],
  [ 4.307274211471829, 52.08387390249157 ]
  ]

];

const coordinates2 = [
  [
    [ 4.30727421, 52.0838739 ],
    [ 4.308168937245766, 52.077487539906365 ],
    [ 4.30733293, 52.0834548 ],
    [ 4.30758, 52.08315 ],
    [ 4.3082, 52.0829 ],
    [ 4.30837, 52.08257 ],
    [ 4.30917964, 52.08188373 ],
    [ 4.30913, 52.08163 ],
    [ 4.30922, 52.08209 ],
    [ 4.3077, 52.08356 ],
    [ 4.30727421, 52.0838739 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 4.30819, 52.07789 ],
    [ 4.30844817, 52.0775652 ],
    [ 4.30843, 52.07755 ],
    [ 4.30884, 52.07688 ],
    [ 4.30919084, 52.07666072 ],
    [ 4.309250676431562, 52.076610658496044 ],
    [ 4.30912, 52.07672 ],
    [ 4.30819, 52.07789 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 4.30844962138449, 52.07548408020292 ],
    [ 4.30846, 52.07541 ],
    [ 4.309538252087693, 52.07573216068474 ],
    [ 4.30895664, 52.07555839 ],
    [ 4.30844962138449, 52.07548408020292 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 4.30883, 52.08102 ],
    [ 4.31039087, 52.0795252 ],
    [ 4.3103, 52.07888 ],
    [ 4.3104, 52.07959 ],
    [ 4.31024, 52.07997 ],
    [ 4.308948777972253, 52.08115286773171 ],
    [ 4.30883, 52.08102 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 4.3093340240790035, 52.07654091862778 ],
    [ 4.3096157998419695, 52.075755330440586 ],
    [ 4.3101, 52.0759 ],
    [ 4.3093340240790035, 52.07654091862778 ]
  ]
]

const intersection = [
[[4.307274212030627,52.083873898502986],[4.308041172159136,52.078399502699355],[4.30733293,52.0834548],[4.30758,52.08315],[4.3082,52.0829],[4.30837,52.08257],[4.30917964,52.08188373],[4.30913,52.08163],[4.30922,52.08209],[4.3077,52.08356],[4.307274212030627,52.083873898502986]]
  ]  


const poly = turf.polygon(coordinates, {
    stroke: '#FF0000',
    fill: '#FF0000',
    'fill-opacity': 0.4,
    'stroke-width': 1
});


const poly2 = turf.polygon(coordinates2, {
    stroke: '#EAF311',
    fill: '#EAF311',
    'fill-opacity': 0.4,
    'stroke-width': 1
});

const poly3 = turf.polygon(intersection, {
    stroke: '#1AA3G1',
    fill: '#1AA3G1',
    'fill-opacity': 0.9,
    'stroke-width': 1
});



const finalIntersection = turf.intersect(turf.polygon(coordinates), turf.polygon(coordinates2))


console.log("finalIntersection=", JSON.stringify(finalIntersection))


return turf.featureCollection([ poly, poly2, poly3 ]);




Problem is in the way you construct poly2 polygon. When you construct GeoJSON polygon from coordinates, first coordinate ring describes actual polygon, but all next rings describe holes in the polygon.
First, with your poly2 polygon, all holes are outside actual polygon, which makes no sense. And second, polygon holes are excluded when making intersection.
Here is how it looks if first ring of coordinates2 is green and the rest are blue:

If you want intersection to use all rings from coordinates2, you have to create multi polygon from them. This can be done like this:
var coordsForMulti = [];
coordinates2.forEach(function(ring, i) {
  var coords = [];
  coords[0] = ring;
  coordsForMulti.push(coords);
});
var multiPoly = turf.multiPolygon(coordsForMulti);

Then intersection:
var intersectPoly = turf.intersect(poly1, multiPoly);

will give you this intersection (blue):

